# Bind dropdown in mvc4 with class using Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to bind the dropdown list in mvc 4 with the dictionary that was in a class file.

my class file is

```
    namespace RealEstate.ViewModel
{
  public class Dropdowns
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> ddlCount()
    {
        Dictionary<Int32, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dict.Add(0, "1");
        dict.Add(1, "2");
        dict.Add(2, "3");
        dict.Add(3, "4");
        dict.Add(4, "5");
        dict.Add(5, "6");
        dict.Add(6, "7");
        dict.Add(7, "8");

        return dict;
    }
}
```

}

i am pass value for controller using viewbag

```
 public ActionResult Save()
    {
Dropdowns ddl = new Dropdowns();
        ViewBag.ddlcount = ddl.ddlCount();

        return View();
    }
```

and recieving it in view like

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.type, ViewBag.ddlcount as List<SelectListItem>)
```

i am using strongly typed view
        @model RealEstate.Models.listing

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller.cs**

```
    public ActionResult Save()
    {
        Dropdowns ddl = new Dropdowns();
        ViewBag.ddlCount= new SelectList(ddl.ddlCount(),"Key", "Value", type);
        return View();
    }
```

**View.cshtml**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlCount", null, htmlAttributes: null})
```